# Determine if User is System Administrator without a query

Tags: apex, describesobject

has anyone found a way to check if the current user is a sysadmin without consuming a query? Seems like something that should be easily determined using Describe but haven't seen a solution to this. Used frequently in my org, and would be great to get rid of a query. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. For this purpose, we created a CurrentUserInfo class that has a number of values automatically lazy-loaded from the database on first use, and cached later uses. A simplified version of our code might look like this:

```
public class CurrentUserInfo {
  public static Boolean isAdmin = false;
  static {
    for(PermissionSetAssignment psa: [SELECT PermissionSet.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()]) {
      isAdmin |= psa.PermissionSet.PermissionsModifyAllData;
    }
  }
}
```

You can add more logic to this to cache as much information as you'd like about the current user. Yes, you still get hit with a query, but only once per transaction, no matter how many times you use it. Actual use of the class works as you might expect:

```
if(CurrentUserInfo.isAdmin) { // they are an administrator...
```

Comment: Also include AND PermissionsCustomizeApplication = TRUE check to ensure its Sys Admin

Comment: @sfdcfox For Winter 23' release, is this still the most effective way answer?

Answer (score -1):

import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import Name from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
import RoleName from '@salesforce/schema/User.UserRole.Name';
import ProfileName from '@salesforce/schema/User.Profile.Name';
import ManagerName from '@salesforce/schema/User.Manager.Name';

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: Id, fields: [Name, RoleName, ProfileName, ManagerName] })
userDetails({ error, data }) {
if (error) {
this.error = error;
} else if (data) {
if (data.fields.Name.value != null) {
this.userName = data.fields.Name.value;
}
if (data.fields.UserRole.value != null) {
this.userRoleName = data.fields.UserRole.value.fields.Name.value;
}
if (data.fields.Profile.value != null) {
this.userProfileName = data.fields.Profile.value.fields.Name.value;
}
if (data.fields.Manager.value != null) {
this.userManagerName = data.fields.Manager.value.fields.Name.value;
}
}

Comment: Code dumps make for poor answers. The explanation is as important as the solution itself.